# Sqlite3: Unexpected error on update with 3 way join

Tags: sqlite

I am getting an unexpected error with SQLite 3.42.0  on a 3 way join. I have narrowed it down to the following test case:

```
create table a (foo TXT, bar_id TXT);
create table b (bar TXT);
insert into a VALUES ('foo', NULL), ('bar', NULL), ('baz', NULL);
insert into b VALUES ('bilbo'),('baz'),('bar'),('foo');
```

The following query works as expected:

```
update a
set bar_id = b1.rowid
from b as b1
where a.foo = b1.bar;
```

However, if I then move to a 3 way join involving row ids as follows:

```
update a
set bar_id = b1.rowid
from b as b1
join b as b2 on b1.rowid = b2.rowid
where a.foo = b2.bar;
```

This generates `Parse Error: no such column: b1.rowid`

Does anyone understand the cause of this error?

Comment: This seems like a bug because the code works fine in version 3.37.2: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ezS6u7cP2mpxxn6HCQJysf/0 but not in version 3.39.1: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ezS6u7cP2mpxxn6HCQJysf/1